# Retornar um valor de váriavel com ZeroClipboard

Tags: jquery, html

Eu estou a usar esta biblioteca https://github.com/zeroclipboard para copiar texto ao clicar no botão para o clipboard do usuário. Estou a tentar encontrar uma forma de alterar o seu funcionamento um pouco, mas sem sucesso.

O básico de uso da biblioteca é:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="d_clip_button" class="clip_button" data-clipboard-text="Copy Me!"  title="Click to copy." style="border:1px solid black; padding:20px;">Copy To Clipboard</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var client = new ZeroClipboard( document.getElementById('d_clip_button') );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

O que eu pretendo alterar é quando o usuário clicar em cima da div de id="d_clip_button" ele tem que retornar um valor JQUERY que está em uma variável para dentro de **data-clipboard-text**, deste modo posso gerar valores dinamicamente de uma base de dados, eu fiz varios testes, mas não consegui achar a solução, será possível fazer isso, ou esta biblioteca só funciona com texto estático? Se a resposta for SIM, tenho alguma forma de fazer o que pretendo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Basta olhar na documentação da biblioteca.](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard/blob/master/docs/instructions.md#text-to-copy)

```
var client = new ZeroClipboard( document.getElementById("d_clip_button") );
client.on( "copy", function (event) {
  var clipboard = event.clipboardData;

  // Pode usar um AJAX aqui para resgatar valores
  // do banco de dados, se quiser.

  clipboard.setData( "text/plain", "Copy me!" );
  clipboard.setData( "text/html", "<b>Copy me!</b>" );
  clipboard.setData( "application/rtf", "{\\rtf1\\ansi\n{\\b Copy me!}}" );
});
```

Comment: Perfeito, funcionando corretamente!